# Metro boot locked me out of windows due to loop

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, manjaro

I managed to successfully dual boot Manjaro and Windows 10, from Windows, using a program called **easyBCD**. It was all working normally, but there was 1 little issue I found, which was that you had to go through the Windows metro boot to select Manjaro. and then go through Manjaro's dual boot process, which I found a bit tedious.

so...

I made the completely destructive choice of changing easybcd's options so that it would skip the boot process and automatically boot Linux. Therefore, every time I choose to boot Windows 10 from Manjaro's grub system, it just automatically takes me back to the grub bootloader. (at least I think that's the case, Windows doesn't load past the message "processing the preset menu...")

**Is there any way I could perhaps edit the Windows 10 boot settings from Linux to fix this?**

I ended up starting the issue by changing these freebcd settings:

- skip the boot menu on.
- set default to Manjaro.

Comment: Probably not. Just boot a Windows ISO (disc/USB) and fix it with `bcdedit` (or `bcdboot`).

Comment: will this get rid of all my data, on the windows 10 partition?

Comment: The programs mentioned will not do that.

Comment: So just to clarify. Do i boot a new windows 10 installation, running it live on my usb, and then i go to bcdedit, and fix the problem? If anyone could provide a full answer on this, that would be amazing!